# How to get coordinates of a point on a circle and its angle to the center

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles

I have a circle. I know the radius (800) and I know the point coordinates (0, -800) under the circle. I double the point and move this one to the right. And a second point now has coordinates (500, -800). I have to define y (z coordinates according to my screenshot) value like a point is located on the circle and define an angle to the center (0, 0, 0).

I have tried:

1. If the bottom point has an angle of 0°, then a point in the middle of the right has a 90° angle. If movement of X axis is located within |0, R| then I can say the angle equals $$(90/R)*500$$. `R` is the radius. But then I got 56.25°. It is incorrect because the direction vector doesn't point to the center.
2. I tried to define an angle using the equation: $$cos(x)*R=500$$ and then I got 0.624999996583 rad = 35.8098619999856°. It is also incorrect for the same reason.

How can I define `y` value and the angle?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't understand how $R\cos x=500$ led to $x\approx0.625.$ Anyway, I'd rather say $R\tan x=500.$

Comment: @AnneBauval  yes. 0.625 rad euals 35,809862°. You can see result on the screenshot. But then a point is not targeted to the center.

Comment: @AnneBauval I mean if I calculate the y coodrnate I get this result - https://imgur.com/a/qjr1MEP using the formula $$sin(0.625)*R$$

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I feel unable to help you. I think some data are missing.

Comment: Try old good Pythagoras' theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your comments. It was my bad. I thought in equation $$800\cos(x) = 500,$$$x = \frac58$, but $$x = \arccos\left(\frac58\right).$$Therefore, I can define the angle this way. So then the y value equals $$R\sin(\text{angle}).$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

The following is very important for everyone working with 2D polar and Cartesian coordinates, especially programmers:
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x &= r \cos \theta \\
y &= r \sin \theta \\
\end{aligned} \right. \quad \iff \quad \left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
\theta &= \operatorname{atan2}(y, x) \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
where $\operatorname{atan2}()$ denotes the [two-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2):
$$\operatorname{atan2}(y, x) = \begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), & x \gt 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + 180°, & x \lt 0, ~ y \ge 0 \\
\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - 180°, & x \lt 0, ~ y \lt 0 \\
+180°, & x = 0, ~ y \gt 0 \\
-180°, & x = 0, ~ y \lt 0 \\
\text{undefined}, & x = 0, ~ y = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
although most programming languages implement $\operatorname{atan2}(0, 0) = 0$.